# Phonegap dom update not immediately reflected in display

Tags: jquery, android, cordova, refresh

I have a Phonegap/jQuery application which is working great, however in one area the DOM is being changed and not displayed until some user input (a touch, drag, anything) triggers the display to re-render.  (This happens on my android phone and tablet, but works in Chrome)

```
function reloadSubscriptions(num) {
    if (subscriptionsStore[num]) {
        for (var x in subscriptionsStore[num]) {
            $('#' + x + 'Subscribe').html('<a href="#" onclick="unsubscribe(\'' + x + '\',\'' + num + '\'); return false;">[UN-SUBSCRIBE]</a>');
        }
    }
    $('#busy').hide();  
}
```

This is the final function in a chain, which does the DOM updates...  Any ideas how I can trigger the application to refresh the display?

I'd be willing to provide the APK and a larger script chunk for demonstration.

I've since gotten this to occur elsewhere, basically any time I update the DOM without changing a lot of the display.

Edit:

The original HTML page includes:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <ul id="menuList" class="menu-list"></ul>
    <div id="otherContent"></div>
</div>
```

When a certain button is pressed, a list of options is loaded into the #menuList.  When they are loaded, a span #`<item-id>`Subscribe is created inside each `<li>`.  After the list is loaded, the original function I posted conditionally updates the span #`<item-id>`Subscribe.

The display changes when the list of options is loaded, but not when the spans are updated after the fact.   Touching the screen then shows the update.

Comment: can you provide more script code?? ideally it should work as it is but may happen that some other script is doing the trick. Also is x~Subscribe element is already available or is it getting created somewhere in the chain??

Comment: @dhaval I added some explanation..

Comment: I have created a fiddle based on your above script can you check whether put together correctly. [http://jsfiddle.net/dhavaln/AnTVC/](http://jsfiddle.net/dhavaln/AnTVC/)

Comment: @dhaval Pretty much, except the call to reloadSubscriptions would be inside loadList.  That process inside a Phonegap app on Android is where the issue is.  Unsubscribe wouldn't appear until a touch.

Comment: I tried running script with phonegap android application but it runs well, even after altering it. As such the code as it is should work. It has to be something else. Can you provide apk??

Comment: @dhaval If you can post an answer stating that in the next 3-4 hours I'll give you the bounty for your effort.

Comment: Do you want me to post the script code I am running in my phonegap application??

Comment: I am having the exact same issue as you.  Were you ever able to find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried following script code in my application which worked without any issue. Although this is just a test code so there is no additionally code running aside.

```
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <ul id="menuList" class="menu-list"></ul>
        <div id="otherContent"></div>
    </div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function reloadSubscriptions(num) {

        // Tried with comments enabled as well
        //for (i = 0; i < num; i += 1) {
        $('#' + i + 'Subscribe').html(
                '<a href="#" onclick="unsubscribe(\'' + i + '\',\'' + i
                        + '\'); return false;">[UN-SUBSCRIBE]</a>');
        //}

        $('#busy').hide();
    }

    function loadList(num) {
        for (i = 0; i < num; i += 1) {
            $("<li>List text <span id='"+ i+"Subscribe'></span></li>")
                    .appendTo($("#menuList"));

            reloadSubscriptions(i);
        }
    }

    loadList(5);
    // reloadSubscriptions(5);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

i think that you have to trigger a JQM refresh action on the page thats your working with
like :

```
$('#somepage').trigger('refresh');
```

since from the small code that you have your changing the markup
check [page scripting](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/pages/page-scripting.html) section **Create vs. refresh: An important distinction**

Comment: interesting... but, this application was not using jQuery Mobile, just plain jQuery.  I've not been able to find a similar function...

Comment: sorry i though i read jqm :( , maybe its stuck in my hear when i read another question, any way in your case am not sure what is the problem is sorry .. have you tried to use jqm , it might solve your refresh problem ..

Comment: After experiencing this, I tried JQM, jqTouch, Sencha Touch, and more... everything seems too slow.

Comment: look my advice since you dont rely on jqm that much dont include the css file, just the structured since from what i have read and tested there is a problem with the css3 which caused this slow issue, and mostly because of the gradient ..

Answer (score 1):

I have seen in 2 applications before. It seems to happen when you make minor changes like just updating a label text. I think Android "thinks" that nothing has changed and doesn't refresh the webview.

Try changing somethin "bigger" along with your small changed like making toggling a transparend div visibility (or anything that the user won't notice).